# Ellipsis in remote rsyslog output

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I have a rsyslog daemon running on a server receiving and aggregating messages from a number of other servers. Occasionally, I see line written which looks like the start of a message, an ellipsis(...), and the end of another, different, message.

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the length of the message, as longer messages get through with out problems.

I have looked through the rsyslog doco without success and searching google for ... is not useful. Have I just missed something in the doco, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elipsis is actually coming from the log4j syslog appender implementation. If the line is "too long" it will be truncated and an elipsis will be written instead.